# order multi columns via mysql

Tags: php, mysql

this is The group table:

```
id   parents_id level  name
------------------------
1      null      0     a
2      1         1     a1
3      1         1     a2
4      null      0     b
5      null         0     c
6      1         2     a3
```

parent_id is id!

Now I wana this result: after fetch and sort:

```
a
a1
a2
a3
b
c
```

I tried with this:

```
SELECT * FROM groups ORDER BY parent_id,level DESC
```

But the result is:

```
a
b
c
a1
a2
a3
```

How can I change the code to get my favorate result?

Comment: It looks like you just want `ORDER BY name`.

Comment: @Barmar I guess this is just a simplified sample...

Comment: If you're implementing hierarchical data in MySQL, see http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ for lots of good ideas.

Comment: yea why are you ordering by parent_id and level if you want it ordered by name??

Comment: No the value of name is just for example...

Answer (score 1):

as you mention that `name` is not relevant this returns, the parent_id group with the parent first, and the rest following. assume also that all ids are positive.

```
select * from yourtable
order by coalesce(parents_id, id), coalesce(parents_id, -1), id
```

Answer (score 0):

Started off complicated...

```
SELECT * FROM groups 
ORDER BY concat(coalesce(lpad(parent_id,10,'0'),lpad(ID,10,'0')), lpad('level',2,'0'), name DESC
```

Got simpler

```
SELECT * FROM groups 
ORDER BY coalesce(lpad(parent_id,10,'0'), lpad(ID,10,'0')), 'level', name DESC
```

and ended up with...

```
SELECT * FROM groups 
ORDER BY coalesce(parent_id, ID), 'level', name DESC
```

This has some assumptions:

- ID parent_ID will not exceed 9,999,999,999
- ID will not exceed 9,999,999,999
- level will not exceed 99.
- mysql will simplicity cast number to string.

What first two did was to generates a padded string for ID and parent ID 
so that values look like

```
00000000100 a
00000000101 a1
00000000101 a2
00000000400 b
00000000500 c
00000000102 a3
```

As you can see when you sort the above by the number it should sort in the requested order for parent with children.  However to get the children in the right order we needed to sort by level next and lastly if level and parent and children match, then by name. However since 000000000101 is listed twice, I needed name to sort a1,a2.

so that values are sorted as requested and then also sorts by name so duplicates have some sorting applied.

However, I realized that we could accomplish the same thing without padding...  level may need to be in ticks for mysql not sure if it's a reserved word...

Answer (score 0):

well, this order all the group together by its name, and inside it, first the parent and then the child ordered

```
select yt.* 
from  yourtable yt
left join yourtable parent on coalesce(yt.parents_id, yt.id) = parent.id
order by parent.name, -- this orders all the group together following parent''s name
        case when yt.parent is null then 0 else 1 end,   -- this put the parent first
        yt.name      -- finally this order by child name
```